# Angularjs "this" is undefined in normal object

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a quiz in angular and i use this code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="choices" ng-click="setSelection(choice)">{{choice}}</li>
</ul>

var choiceSelection = {
        isSelected: false,
        userAnswers: [],
        setSelection: function(choice) {
            this.userAnswers.push(choice);
            console.log(this.userAnswers);
        }
    };


$scope.setSelection = choiceSelection.setSelection;
```

I want to store the users choice in the userAnswers array, but the this in setSelection is undefined and therefore this.userAnswers nor this.isSelected works. This code works in normal JS, I just tested it.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the proper value for `this` to your setSelection function:

```
var choiceSelection = new function ( ) {
    this.isSelected = false;
    this.userAnswers = [];

    this.setSelection = function(choice) {
        this.userAnswers.push(choice);
        console.log(this.userAnswers);
    }.bind( this );
} ;

$scope.setSelection = choiceSelection.setSelection;
```